# Preventing the creation of anonymous classes from traits, without an enclosing object

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following trait and object:

```
trait NoAnon {
    val i: Int
}

object NoAnon {
    def create = new NoAnon {
        val i = 123
    }
}
```

I would like to prevent anonymous instances of `NoAnon` from being created outside of the companion object. ie. only `create` in this example should be allowed to do this. I can enclose these within another object, and make the trait private to that object to accomplish this:

```
object Ctx {

    private[Ctx] trait NoAnon {
        val i: Int
    }

    object NoAnon {
        def create = new Ctx.NoAnon {
            val i = 123
        }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to do this without the enclosing object `Ctx`?

To be a little more clear, can traits mimic the functionality of a private abstract class constructor? That is, the following example, except with a trait.

```
abstract class NoAnon private[NoAnon] {
    val i: Int
}

object NoAnon {
    def create = new NoAnon {
        val i = 123
    }
}
```

Comment: make the trait (or its constructor) private to the package?

Comment: That's not really much different than just making it private to an object, though. I'm thinking this is not possible as stated without side-stepping the issue.

Comment: @m-z is there any reason you don't like the proposed solutions? That is, per-object private trait and per-package private trait?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Not particularly. It's a personal preference not to wrap them like that, but I'm more so just wondering if there is a better built-in way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use a class with a private constructor and extend that with your trait.  You can even nest that class in the companion object:

```
trait NoAnon extends NoAnon.type#NoAnonCheck { 
    val i: Int
}

object NoAnon {
    class NoAnonCheck private[NoAnon]
    def create = new NoAnon { 
        val i = 1 
    }   
}
```

Then if you tried:

```
new NoAnon { val i = 2 }
```

You get:

```
error: constructor NoAnonCheck in class NoAnonCheck cannot be accessed in <$anon: NoAnonCheck with NoAnon>
```

But you can use `NoAnon.create`.  Other than adding something like this, I don't think there is currently a pure way to do this in Scala.

Of course as you know and as mentioned in the comments, the other options are to make the the trait private to the scope of an enclosing object or package.

Comment: This seems somewhat convoluted, but also seems like the only way to avoid an enclosing object / sealed & secluded trait. Clever, nonetheless.

Comment: I agree that this is definitely convoluted – probably too hokey for anything in production, in my opinion!